# Quais são as diferenças entre um editor de código, editor de texto e um IDE?

Tags: terminologia, ide, editor-de-texto

Qual a diferença entre um editor de código, um editor de texto e um IDE?

As pessoas afirmam que o Visual Studio Code é um editor de *código* e não uma IDE. Eu realmente vejo que a diferença entre o VS Code e o VS é inigualável, é como se o VS fosse um Deus em relação ao VS Code.

Também vejo dizerem que Sublime Text e Notepad++ é um editor de *texto*.

Então me surgiram as dúvidas:

- O que define que o "programa" é um editor de *texto*, um editor de *código* ou um IDE? (Principalmente um editor de texto e um editor de código, pra ser sincero me parecem ser a mesma coisa).
- Um IDE também é um editor de texto e código?
- Até que pontos eles podem ser considerados o que são?
- Existem outros relacionados?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Editor de texto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) é para editar textos não especificados, nada tem a ver com programação, embora um código possa ser escrito em um editor de texto.

Um [editor de código](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) é especializado, tem recursos que ajudam em codificação, há auxílios para melhor aproveitar as linguagens de programação ou outros tipos de definição. Além dos recursos que permitem edição de uma forma mais apropriada para os movimentos que um código costuma ter, e não ter os recursos típicos de edição de textos formatados como uma carta ou algo parecido (não faz negrito, parágrafo, etc.), ele costuma ter *colorimento* para ajudar a visualização, dicas e auto *completamento* de sintaxe, entre outras facilidades. Geralmente ele pode ser mais configurável para dar mais ergonomia e usabilidade ao programador com seu estilo e linguagem. É comum ter um sistema de *plugin*. Claro que todo editor de código é um editor de texto em um sentido geral.

Até onde sei não tem uma linha clara onde o editor de código começa ser um IDE. Imagino que seja quando faz algo além da edição do código. Certamente todo IDE tem um editor de texto. Tem também chamada ao compilador, *debugger* e ferramentas de análise, gerenciamento do projeto, um *help*, provavelmente um editor de telas, relatórios e outros componentes visuais, controle de versão, análise de performance, entre outros. O sistema de *plugin* costuma ser mais abrangente.

Claro que um editor de código pode editar um texto simples, plano, sem formatação. Assim como pode editar JSON, XML. Não considero os dois editores citados como de texto. Um Notepad++ pode editar texto simples ou código.

Pra mim Sublime e Notepad++ são essencialmente editores de código. Como não tem uma definição formal clara e irrefutável certamente há quem discorde.

E considero o Visual Studio Code um [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). Pode não ser tão poderoso, mas ele é muito mais que um editor de código, permite cuidar do projeto como um todo.

O Visual Studio é um [ALM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management) (Application Lifecycle Management) ou (ADLM onde o desenvolvimento é incluso) que é um IDE glorificado. Além das atividades típicas do desenvolvimento ele cuida de outros pontos, como configuração, testes diversos, implantação, requerimentos, arquitetura, manutenção, mudanças e problemas, documentação, qualidade, governança, colaboração, enfim, o projeto em um sentido amplo e outras atividades ligadas ao projeto que não são o desenvolvimento propriamente dito.

Um ALM possui modelagem UML ou outro estilo parecido, acesso a banco de dados, integração contínua, entre outros. Alguns ALMs não possuem um IDE. Novamente, a linha do que é um IDE e um ALM não é bem definida.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Complementando [a resposta excelente do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276005/41056):

- Editor de texto: não é especializado em edição de código, mas pode editar código. Exemplo: Notas do iPhone e Bloco de Notas do Windows.
- Editor de código: especializado em código. Pode ter auto-complete (geralmente bem burro, mas faz seu trabalho), highlighting de código e mais. Para que fique melhor e aumente a produtividade do desenvolvedor, existem plugins que o deixam mais completo.
- IDE: faz tudo que o editor de código faz e ainda cuida de projetos, testes, depuração, navegação entre código com mais precisão, refatoração e mais.

Hoje há a tendência de transformar editores de código em IDEs instalando milhares de plugins. [O editor de código Atom, por exemplo, tem diversas extensões que o falam que o transformam em IDE.](http://blog.atom.io/2017/09/12/announcing-atom-ide.html)

Para meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, eu uso somente um editor de código e o Terminal. É o Sublime, mas com poucos plugins e algumas configurações que resolvem meu problema. Se estiver em dúvida em o que usar, veja o que é viável para seu *stack* e use o que for produtivo para você.

Em resumo:

| Editor de Código | Editor de Texto | IDE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Não especializado | Especializado | Completo e integrado |
| Ex: notepad.exe | Muitos plugins | Testes e depuração |
| Ex: Notas do iOS | Syntax highlight | Ex: Visual Studio |

Comment: Essa tabela no final não ficou legal, ficou toda torta

Comment: Eita! Acho que estamos em resoluções diferentes (https://imgur.com/a/jrDLp). De qualquer forma, tirei. Obrigado @JeffersonQuesado :D

Comment: Nossa, bastante! Estou usando o app do stack exchange para iPhone, deve ter sido o jeito dele interpretar que quebrou tudo. Mas essa imagem ficou bem bonitinha, acho que dá para por ela

Comment: Pronto! @JeffersonQuesado

Answer (score 0):

IDE é vida.

Essencialmente, o IDE, ao contrário de um editor de textos comum (Sublime ou Notepad++), trabalha no escopo de um "Projeto", ao invés de arquivos individuais. Você abre um "projeto" nele, e ele escaneia todos os arquivos daquele projeto, e você tem várias funcionalidades que te ajudam a mexer no código, como:

- Ver todos os lugares onde uma função ou método estão sendo usados
- Ao usar uma função ou método, você pode pular para onde ela está sendo definida
- Te informa a lista de parâmetros obrigatórios e opcionais ao usar uma função ou método
- Te informa se você passou um parâmetro com o tipo inesperado (eg: Vc passou uma string, e a função esperava um array)
- Você consegue renomear ou mover arquivos e funções em massa, em todo o projeto
- De uma maneira geral, o IDE tem um "engine PHP" que consegue entender o código PHP, enquanto um editor de texto só vê "texto", não vê "código PHP". Ambos usam cores para deixar o código mais legível para seres humanos, mas o IDE sabe se a sintaxe está correta ou não.
- Enfim, tem várias coisas

É grande, complicado, difícil, mas se você insistir persistentemente em usar, em um ou dois meses você não vai querer outra coisa. Eu usava Sublime antes, e migrar pro PhpStorm pra mim foi um processo difícil, mas hoje não sinto mais necessidade nenhuma do Sublime

Se você edita muitos arquivos via FTP por exemplo, a IDE não é tão util assim, pois ela é mais útil para projetos desenvolvidos na máquina local.